# How can I direct all visitors to https://www.example.com?

Tags: redirect

I thought I had it right but when I type just example.com in the browser it isn't redirecting, I get the no server IP error.

Code I have now is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Cheers

Comment: Hope someone will help out because I have literally tried all combinations and still I can't get non www to www working.

Onlly http://www to https://www is working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```